# Why az login command does not work on Azure when executed with power shell command that runs from dot net code?

Tags: asp.net, azure, powershell, command-line-interface, runspace

I have an ASP.Net Web Application which tries to log into Azure using power shell commands. The following code is being used for this purpose:

```
        Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
        runspace.Open();
        Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
        pipeline.Commands.AddScript("az login -u 'vtripathi@hsdyn.com' -p '********'");
        pipeline.Commands.Add("Out-String");
        var output = pipeline.Invoke();
        string result = output[0].ToString();
```

The problem here is that when I run this application locally on my system, it manages to log into Azure successfully, but when I deploy the same application on Azure app service, I get the below error:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.    
The term 'az' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

Please suggest what might be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Az Login is a command from the Azure CLI, therefore to run this the CLI needs to be installed on the machine you are running it on. CLI will not be installed on an Azure Web app.

If your writing a .net web app you really want to be using the .net Azure API to talk directly to the Azure REST API, not trying to use CLI.